# Multiple Smart Contracts in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

How can I implement more than one smart contract in the same application of Hyperledger fabric ? Which configuration file contains the settings to achieve this ?

Answer (score 8):

I will answer your question using the Fabcar example from the Hyperledger Fabric version 1.4. And my answer is based on Javascript Implementation.

If you see the folder structure you would see that there is a Chaincode folder which contains the fabcar.js(chaincode/fabcar/javascript/lib/fabcar.js) chaincode.

> A smart contract is defined within a chaincode. Multiple smart contracts can be defined within the same chaincode. When a chaincode is deployed, all smart contracts within it are made available to applications.

In this particular chaincode there is only one smart contract i.e FabCar.And you might observe the file only exports one contract.

If you want to add more smart contracts, Just create another Class in the same chaincode, which extends the Contract class and then export it. Below I have shown an example.

```
  class FabCar extends Contract {
     ...
     ...
     ...
   } 
   class NewContract1 extends Contract {
     ...
     ...
     ...
   } 
   class NewContract2 extends Contract {
     ...
     ...
     ...
   } 

   module.exports.FabCar = FabCar;
   module.exports.NewContract1 = NewContract1;
   module.exports.NewContract2 = NewContract2;
```

You need to make a few changes in the index.js (chaincode/fabcar/javascript/index.js).

```
'use strict';

const FabCar = require('./lib/fabcar').FabCar;
const NewContract1 = require('./lib/careonlineChaincode').NewContract1;
const NewContract2 = require('./lib/careonlineChaincode').NewContract2;
module.exports.FabCar = FabCar;
module.exports.NewContract1 = NewContract1;
module.exports.NewContract1 = NewContract2;
module.exports.contracts = [ FabCar, NewContract1, NewContract2 ];
```

And now for the Client Application, you can refer to the Fabar Client Implementations. (fabric-sample/fabcar/javascript/invoke.js). Below I have shown an example on how you can easily call these different contracts.

```
const contract = network.getContract('fabcar', 'FabCar');
//getContact(chaincode name, contract name)
const newContract1 = network.getContract('fabcar', 'NewContract1');
const newContract2 = network.getContract('fabcar', 'NewContract2');
```

Now you can individually call these contracts and use their transactions.

example:

```
await contract.submitTransaction('someTrancsaction', 'someData');
await newContract1.submitTransaction('someTrancsactionFromThisContract', 'someDataFromHere');
await newContract2.submitTransaction('differentTransacation', 'randomdata');
```

Hope you understood the entire example. If you need more clarification please comment. I didn't go to touch upon how to install and instantiate the chaincode. For that, you can refer the answer by @Artem. But his approach was installing 2 chaincodes on the same channel. That might also work, I'm not sure. But this is a simple approach with only one Chaincode.

Comment: I faced the same situation and implemented what you have suggested worked. In my case all my contract classes are in individual js files;I refer in the index.js. Before seeing your answer, I did not specify the contract class name in the client application. Now I am specifying (chaincode, contract), it works like a charm! My 4 days of struggle came to an end! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Let me clarify a bit on Sergio answer:

> First of all you need to be aware that to run multiple smart contracts in same blockchain you have to create a custom channel between peers PER smart contract.

This is not precisely correct as you are not required to install chaincode (smartcontract) *PER* channel. It's completely up to your specific application, design, trust model and business case requirements. One channel could have as many chaincodes instantiated as need. The procedure to achieve this is fairly simple, you just need to install all required chaincodes into peer and instantiate each one of them on the channel you going to use them. For example you can install two chaincodes which aims to interact within scope of single channel say "MyChannel" the following way:

1. Install first chaincode

   `peer chaincode install -o localhost:7050 -n myCC1 -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincode/mychaincode1`
2. Install second chaincode

   `peer chaincode install -o localhost:7050 -n myCC2 -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincode/mychaincode2`
3. Instantiate both

   `peer chaincode instantiate -o localhost:7050 -n myCC1 -v 1.0 -C MyChannel -c '{"Args":[]}'`

   `peer chaincode instantiate -o localhost:7050 -n myCC2 -v 1.0 -C MyChannel -c '{"Args":[]}'`

Thus you will have two chaincodes `myCC1` and `myCC2` installed and instantiated in the scope of channel `MyChannel`.

Please follow official [tutorial](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/chaincode.html) and consider to get connected to [Rocket.Chat](http://chat.hyperledger.org) to get more help from the expert community.

Comment: One chaincode can contain multiple smart contracts. So it is up to the design and requirements of the application. You can have the contracts in different chaincodes and install them separately on the channel or you can have multiple smart contracts in the same chain code and install the chain code, which will make all the contracts available to all the applications.

Answer (score 4):

Taking the same FabCar example and assuming the following:

**1) you want one chaincode with multiple smart contracts and**

**2) each smart contract for that chaincode would be in a separate file.**

To implement the solution noted above you would do the following given you have the same [chaincode structure](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/chaincode/fabcar/javascript) and [application structure](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/fabcar/javascript) as shown in Hyperledger/fabric-samples.

Note, that you can have multiple chaincodes too, but I will not focus on that here. To read more about multiple chaincodes, go [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/developapps/contractname.html).

The below code snippets for javascript chaincode language.

**File 1: lib/fabcarcontract.js**

```javascript
class FabCarContract extends Contract {
   constructor() {
        // Unique smart contract name when multiple contracts per chaincode
        super('FabCarContract');
   }
   // ... (add smart contract functions here)
}
module.exports = FabCarContract;
```

**File 2: lib/newcontract1.js**

```javascript
class NewContract1 extends Contract {
   constructor() {
       // Unique smart contract name when multiple contracts per chaincode
       super('NewContract1');
   }
  // ... (add smart contract functions here)
}
module.exports = NewContract1;
```

**File 3: lib/newcontract2.js**

```javascript
class NewContract2 extends Contract {
   constructor() {
        //Unique smart contract name when multiple contracts per chaincode
        super('NewContract2');
   }
   // ... (add smart contract functions here)
}
module.exports = NewContract2;
```

Now we must reference these contracts within our [index.js](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/chaincode/fabcar/javascript/index.js) file which is at the root level of the smart contract directory.

**Index file: index.js**

```javascript
'use strict';

const FabCarContract = require('./lib/fabcarcontract');
const NewContract1 = require('./lib/newcontract1');
const NewContract2 = require('./lib/newcontract2');

module.exports.FabCarContract = FabCarContract;
module.exports.NewContract1 = NewContract1;
module.exports.NewContract2 = NewContract2;
module.exports.contracts = [ FabCarContract, NewContract1, NewContract2 ];
```

Note that our name field within our [package.json](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/chaincode/fabcar/javascript/package.json#L2) file **creates our chaincode name** and that the chaincode name is the default smart contract name **if there is only one smart contract defined.** Since we have multiple, we must reference each smart contract within our chaincode by referencing `network.getContract('fabcar', 'NewContract1');` and only then we can use the functions defined in our NewContract1 file.

Let's look at an example of how we would reference our contract now.

In our application folder -> given we have the proper credentials/wallet structure to access our smart contract, we can check the [invoke.js](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/fabcar/javascript/invoke.js) file to see how to actually invoke different smart contract within our chaincode.

**invoke.js**

```javascript
const network = await gateway.getNetwork('mychannel');

// first we get the chaincode i.e. fabcar, 
// then reference which smart contract within that chaincode we want. 
// here we do NewContract1 but it could have easily been NewContract2 or FabCarContract 
// because we have defined all three of those in our chaincode folder
const contract = network.getContract('fabcar', 'NewContract1');

// now we have access to all functions within NewContract1 file.
await contract.submitTransaction(.....);
```

Now, if we wanted to gain access to functions defined in `NewContract2` we would just change the code above to get contract for a smart contract named `NewContract2` and so on.

Comment: Be noted that there is no multiple smart controls in one chaincode. We use to called smart contract in Etherum terminology and chaincode in fabric terminology. One chaincode can have multiple files aka packages. You cannot install multiple chaincodes at one go

Comment: @NarendranathReddy did you read fabric docs? In there the doc that I linked, it states you can have multiple smart contracts per chaincode.

Comment: Yes you are correct basically Iam from golang when hyperledger releases three years back it was fully focused on go and Iam not sure how this will applicable with golang and dint check this with Nodejs will upvote thanks

Comment: @HoreaPorutiu thanks for a nice answer! But I have a question: how can I call function of one contracts inside another contracts in one chaincode? Do I need to call `stub.invokeCahincode` with the name of current chaincode?

Comment: @GeorgeMA  You can do so with the following 2 lines of code   ``` const contract = network.getContract('fabcar', 'NewContract1');  await contract.submitTransaction(functionName, args);  ```  note that the submitTransaction line is doing the same thing stub.invokeChaincode is doing, but it is using the fabric-network class, instead of the [ChainCode Stub class](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-chaincode-node/release-1.4/api/fabric-shim.ChaincodeStub.html#invokeChaincode__anchor). So by doing getCtronact on the fabcar chaincode, you have access to all smart contracts in that cc

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to be aware that to run multiple smart contracts in same blockchain you have to create a custom channel between peers. In that channel, as many as requested smart contract can be installed

Just following the same procedure to compile, instantiate and run the mart contract over one channel, you just need to repeat this process for every smart contract you want to use

Answer (score 0):

In the diagram,

[image]

chaincode A has three smart contracts defined within it, whereas chaincode B has four smart contracts. See how the chaincode name is used to fully qualify a particular smart contract.

The ledger structure is defined by a set of deployed smart contracts. That’s because the ledger contains facts about the business objects of interest to the network (such as commercial paper within PaperNet), and these business objects are moved through their lifecycle (e.g. issue, buy, redeem) by the transaction functions defined within a smart contract.

In most cases, a chaincode will only have one smart contract defined within it. However, it can make sense to keep related smart contracts together in a single chaincode.

For example, commercial papers denominated in different currencies might have contracts

> EuroPaperContract, DollarPaperContract, YenPaperContract

which might need to be kept synchronized with each other in the channel to which they are deployed.