# Multiple interconnected object types in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm building a system based on Hyperledger Fabric that needs to store information relating to:

1. a list of funds
2. a list of partners (investors) investing in those funds, and
3. a list of subscriptions, representing the relationship between a fund and a partner

Each of these is a separate type of object, with their own set of fields, and needs to be stored and queried independently. Both the fund object and the partner object should include an array of their related subscriptions.

However, I am finding it very difficult to find examples of chaincodes with this kind of structure. All of the objects are strongly interconnected (the modification of one object's data directly implies the modification of the others), so I'd like them to be stored on a single chaincode, but the operations used on them are very different.  Are namespaces intended to be used this way?

I've tried storing them as separate contracts on the same chaincode (using the top answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48334334/multiple-smart-contracts-in-hyperledger-fabric/55160951) question):

papercontract.js

```
class FundContext extends Context {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.subList = new SubList(this);
        this.fundList = new FundList(this);
        this.partnerList = new PartnerList(this);
    }
}

class PartnerContext extends Context...
class SubContext extends Context...


class FundContract extends Contract {
    constructor() {
        super('fund');
    }
    async createFund(ctx, id, name, amount_committed, amount_raised) {
        ...
    }
}
...
class SubContract extends Contract...
class PartnerContract extends Contract...
...
module.exports.FundContract = FundContract;
module.exports.PartnerContract = PartnerContract;
module.exports.SubContract = SubContract;
```

index.js

```
const SubContract = require('./lib/papercontract').SubContract;
const FundContract = require('./lib/papercontract').FundContract;
const PartnerContract = require('./lib/papercontract').PartnerContract;
module.exports.SubContract = SubContract;
module.exports.FundContract = FundContract;
module.exports.PartnerContract = PartnerContract;
module.exports.contracts = [ SubContract, FundContract, PartnerContract ];
```

issue.js

```
const contract = await network.getContract('papercontract','FundContract');
await contract.submitTransaction('createFund', data._id, data.name, data.amount_committed, data.amount_raised);
```

But that returns the error:

```
Error: Contract name is not known: FundContract
```

I am able to get around this by storing the object type (in string form) as the "class" field, and finding objects by searching for both the id and class, which...works, but it feels *very* messy to store a bunch of completely different object types in a single array.  I doubt that this is the way that it is intended to be used.

I'm not sure why I'm getting the above error, or if that would even be the best way of handling the core issue to begin with. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In your fund contract constructor, you are registering the contract as `fund` not `FundContract`.  So try `const contract = await network.getContract('papercontract','fund');` or replace `super('fund')` with `super('FundContract')`.

Comment: But on your broader question, will you have individual operations which need to update multiple types of state?

Comment: @GariSingh Yes, that is the idea - operations need to update multiple objects at once (a subscription update must also update its associated fund and partner within a single chaincode call).

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to implemet different smart contracts in different files, it helps to organize your code:

```
const SubContract = require('./lib/SubContract.js');
const FundContract = require('./lib/FundContract.js');
const PartnerContract = require('./lib/PartnerContract.js');
module.exports.contracts = [SubContract,FundContract,PartnerContract];
```

Concerning your organizational issue, if you implement abstractions of the objects you are manipulating in your contracts (state and state list), as illustrated [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/tutorial/commercial_paper.html), you are able to save different objects in different arrays. In this manner, querying your world state will be more straightforward.

Is that clear?

Comment: If I do that, is it then possible to query other object types from inside a particular contract?  That is, if FundContract has a findById() function, can a function in the PartnerContract call FundContract.findById() to find a fund by id?

Comment: Depends on the implementation: if the findById queries the world state and retrieves the results, then the PartnerContract can just import the FundContract and use its primitives.

Nonetheless, if you are using the context, things change. The context, which is where the "StateList"s are saved, are unique for each smart contract instantiation. I believe you lose context across contracts.

Comment: Is it possible to call a different context from within a single function, and use that to update objects of different types using this method?  (i.e. Fund and Partners have a list of subscriptions, and SubContract has a function to add a subscription, which should simultaneously add its ID to the fund and partner objects it is associated with.)

Comment: That is a very good question. I don't think so - contexts allow you to manage data across transactions of the same smart contract. I am unsure, let me check it and I'll come back to you

Comment: You cannot use the context the way you would like to. You have to query other objects from your smart contract, using the appropriate abstraction, and then to perform updates there

Comment: This didn't really solve the problem then, but I'll award it the bounty anyway because you're the only one who answered in the allotted time.